# What is this black patch on the ocean floor featured on Google Maps?

Tags: islands, caribbean

I would like to visit this location around latitude 14.346756 & longitude -80.223648. However, there is a black patch on the ocean floor in [Google Maps (only visible in satellite view)](https://www.google.com/maps/@14.3467567,-80.2236483,70346m/data=!3m1!1e3).

[image: black patch on the ocean floor]

What is this?

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/n1FQM) is the same location in Bing maps.

Comment: How would you even consider this a "travel" question?

Comment: That looks an awful lot like the island from *Lost*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: I had forgotten where I put my submarine, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert did it, too. My flag was marked as Helpful, but it seems like nothing has happened here yet...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you zoom in, an atoll appears in that area:

[image]

Yet, this looks a little strange.

But also have a look at the group of four black  spots north of your area. If you zoom in, the spots are suddenly filled with satellite images.

This is just a guess, but I think the usual satellite images are overlaid by a layer of ocean images, and this layer is made transparent where there are coast lines or other areas where satellite images would be better.

While the ocean layer is the same for almost all zoom levels, the satellite images are incomplete and not available for all zoom levels. And if there is no satellite image data, the hole in the ocean layer appears black.

(if someone wants to hide something there, it would be less suspicious to let it look like ocean)

**EDIT:**

While Google Maps does not show anything in its map layer there, OpenStreetMap contains much more detailed information, including the name of that place: [Serrana bank](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=14.3467567N%2080.2236483W#map=11/14.3472/-80.2235)

Comment: But what island *is* it? Does it have a name?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Actually, no. Google Earth has no maps, and Google Maps (normal and mobile) just displays blue ocean at that location.

Comment: @sweber Oh, you're right. I had zoomed out, switched to map view, zoomed back in to roughly the same place and confused _Serranilla_ Bank (about 160km north-north-east) with _Serrana_ Bank.

Comment: There is a similar feature about 95km SSE (Roncador Cay) which is visible in OpenStreetMap but blacked out on Google Maps (even if you zoom in): https://www.google.com/maps/@13.5817221,-80.0917016,4756m/data=!3m1!1e3

I agree it is probably not deliberately concealed but just missing from the satellite imagery database.

Answer (score 24):

I think it's Serrana Bank / Banco de Serrana, "a mostly underwater reef with 6 cays." [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serrana_Bank)

The Google imagery is misleading in that it looks like the entire area is an island. The color change is mainly due to the relatively shallow depth in the area with the edges being the reefs.

And, surprise! there used to be a US military base there.

Comment: The color change is not due to the shallow depth; it is caused by the overlap with a different set of images taken under different circumstances (specifically, having different hue/saturation)

Comment: The island looks like a penis? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serrana_Bank

Answer (score 6):

Its nothing - its an artefact introduced by the Google Maps mapping system due to poor data, imagery or other issue.

There are loads of similar artefacts in the Google Maps product forum topic ["Data Problems Compendium v 1110 January 19, 2012"](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gec-data-discussions/z2rEahyQa3U/XQqhyrG4Y_YJ)